# convert spark based regular expression to work on regular strings in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have few regular expression that i am using on a spark dataframe listed below.

```
val codes = Array("0742", "0763", "0780")
df.withColumn("value1",regexp_replace($"code1", "[0]*(0\\d+)", "$1"))

df.withColumn(
  "value2",
  when($"value1".isin(codes: _*), $"value1")
    .otherwise(regexp_replace($"value1", "^[0]*(\\d{4}.*?)[0]*$", "$1")))


df.withColumn(
  "final_value",
  when($"value2".isin(codes: _*), $"value2").otherwise(
    when(length($"value2") >= 6 || length($"value2") < 4, null)
      .otherwise(regexp_replace($"value2", "(^|[^0-9])0+", "$1")))
)
```

How can i convert these to use on regular strings using scala and not on spark dataframe fields?

Comment: Does your question simply boil down to “how do I use regular expressions in Scala”? If so, can you show us what you have tried, or at least researched?